# How to POST data from js to php scripts other than controllers in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to post some data from my js to a php script which is not a controller using ajax but I can't get it to work. I put the script in `app/Classes`
 Here is what I've done so far.
My Javascript:
`$.ajax({
    url:'apps/Classes/TheScript.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {data: 'some data'}
});`

TheScript.php

```
namespace App\Classes;
class TheScript{
   public function get() {
      return $_POST['data'];
   }
}
```

I tried to use it in my controller like this:

```
use App\Classes\TheScript;
class MyController extends Controller {
  function home(){
    $script= new TheScript();
    $data = $script->get();
    return view('home',['data' => $data]);
  }
}
```

When I run this, I get the error `Undefined index: data` in the TheScript.php get() function.
 My question is, is there a way to refer to another script that isn't a controller from my ajax url? How can I achieve this? Thank you

Comment: in wich file MyController class is saved?

Comment: It is saved in the `app\Http\Controllers` directory

Comment: What does `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'))` say ?

Comment: It says string(0) ""

Comment: I did that and still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wire your request directly to your php script attached as closure to a Laravel route like this:

js:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'apps/classes/thescript',
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {data: 'some data'}
});
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('apps/classes/thescript', function()
  {
  $data = Input::get('data');
  $script = new TheScript;
  $script->data = $data;
  $script->save();
  return view('home',['data' => $data]);
  });
```

Comment: If I declear TheScript as an instance, how will I get the "$data" valuable? Do I have to return this variable?

Comment: You could instantiate your class and add $data received by ajax call as its property. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you are using apache and `public/` is you `DocumentRoot`)

If you want to access files outside the DocumentRoot, you should use `Alias`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  #...
  DocumentRoot "YOUR_PATH_/public"
  Alias /app YOUR_PATH_/app
  #...
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

Now you can access the `app/Classes/TheScript.php`

Change `TheScript.php` to return some data.

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['data'];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Change the ajax request url to: `'/app/Classes/TheScript.php'`